# Show/Hide Function

Tags: javascript, show-hide

This is probably a really stupid question but I'm not familiar with JavaScript.

I have two different drop-down menus. If you choose the "other" option, a text box appears to write your request.

When I coded for the first menu, it worked. When I coded for the second one, only the second menu works, disabling the show/hide function for the first menu.

```js
  function showfield(name){
    if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
    else document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
  }
 
 function hidefield() {
 document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
 }

 function showfield(name){
    if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div2').style.display="block";
    else document.getElementById('div2').style.display="none";
  }
 
 function hidefield() {
 document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';
 }
```

```html
 <body onload="hidefield()">
   <table>
     <tbody>
           <tr>
                        <td>
                        <select onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                        <option value=" ">-- Please select --</option>
                        <option value="All">All</option>
                        <option value="Clipped">Clipped</option>
                        <option value="Per Post-It">Per Post-It</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <div id="div1">Other: <input type="text" name="other" /></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <select onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                        <option value=" ">-- Please select --</option>
                        <option value="Binding Element">Binding Element</option>
                        <option value="Folder/Binder">Folder/Binder</option>
                        <option value="Tabs">Tabs</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <div id="div2">Other: <input type="text" name="other" /></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </body>
```

Comment: You are defining the same pair of functions twice. Of course only one of them can really be used.

Comment: Both functions have the same name?

Comment: Could you explain what you want your code to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you’re declaring a variable (or function), you can only have one function with each name. Otherwise, the last one defined will override the others. In your case, I would either change the names of the second group, or change `showField` and `hideField` to take another parameter: `id`. For the first ones, pass `"other1"` and for the second ones, pass `"other2"`. You should also rename your `other` fields to different names.

Answer (score 0):

Having 4 different functions seem a little unneccesarry (and illegal - functions can't have duplicate names). You can write a single method to take care of hiding and showing any object:

```
function showObject (obj) {
    obj.style.display = "";
}

function hideObject (obj) {
    obj.style.display = "none";
}
```

Then, when calling the method from an object, you can do something like that:
<... `onchange="showfield(document.getElementById(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value));" .../>`

And of course, a solution for **jQuery** fans:

```
function showObject (id) {
    $("#" + id).show();
}

function hideObject (id) {
    $("#" + id).hide();
}
```

And in this case, the element's name will be passed and not the element itself:
 `onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" .../>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did declare the function hidefield twice, the function name has to be unique so the second function should have another name.
The second thing is that you have no function to show div1, since your showfunction only selects the div div2

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help!

I changed the function names to be unique and added the different functions in the onload event in the body tag.

```js
function showfield(name) {
  if (name == 'Other') document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
  else document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "none";
}

function hidefield() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
}

function showBreak(name) {
  if (name == 'Other') document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block";
  else document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
}

function hideBreak() {
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Job Ticket</title>
        
    </head>
    <body onload="hidefield(); showBreak();">
        <table class="webform" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <p>Copying/Scanning</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <select onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value=" ">-- Please select --</option>
                    <option value="All">All</option>
                    <option value="Clipped">Clipped</option>
                    <option value="Per Post-It">Per Post-It</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div id="div1">Other:
                    <input type="text" name="whatever" />
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <p>Document Breaks</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <select onchange="showBreak(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value=" ">-- Please select --</option>
                    <option value="All">All</option>
                    <option value="Clipped">Clipped</option>
                    <option value="Per Post-It">Per Post-It</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div id="div2">Other:
                    <input type="text" name="whatever" />
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```